# Conditions in Fragment Shader OpenGl

Tags: opengl, textures, fragment-shader, texture-mapping, vertex-shader

I have a cuboid I want to colour on 4 sides and use texture from an image on the other two sides. I am making a game, and all other objects are just coloured.

Now, I have only one fragment shader that currently uses the colour buffer to set colours to all the objects.

How do I get it to set the texture just for the two faces of this cuboid?

I would need some sort of variable I would want to pass from the program to the shader, that too only for those (2 faces * 2 triangles * 3 vertices) 12 vertices. How do I go about this, or is there any other way?

Comment: @Rabbid76, currently I was building upon a game that had a lot of pre-written elements, and there was a convenient createObject function, and I never had to worry about shaders. If that's the only way, I'll go for a second shader, but I'm wondering if there is an easier work around as I think switching shaders for this one object will be a hassle.

Comment: @Rabbid76: Actually, they don't. Most modern AAA games use very few shaders. Since the cost of changing shaders is high, they avoid it whenever possible, preferring to use "ubershaders" with uniform conditions instead. In this case, the standard way to solve it is to give every object a texture, but have the texture be a tiny, white texture for the cases where you don't see a texture. That's better than using a conditional statement.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas  By uniform condition, you mean use the 'uniform' keyword to make a condition?

Comment: Uniform condition: The use if conditions that only depend on uniform variables or constants (and not on varyings).